# What is the set of all polynomial relations between the sides of a triangle and its area?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Heron's formula gives us one polynomial relation between the sides $a$, $b$ and $c$ of a triangle, and its area $A$:

$$A^2=s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$$

where $s=\frac{a+b+c}2$. But is there a systematic way of working out the set of *all* polynomial relations $P(a, b, c, A)=0$? That is, can we work out the set of polynomials $P\in\mathbb Q[a, b, c, A]$ such that $P(a, b, c, A)=0$ whenever $(a,b,c,A)$ are the side-lengths and area of a triangle?

I can see that this is related to algebraic geometry, but I don't know anything about that area. I was hoping an answer to this question could provide an interesting motivated example of basic algebraic geometry concepts.

Comment: I think we would get just the multiples of $A^2\, -\, s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$.

Comment: @Berci If $H$ is Heron's polynomial and $X$ is the set of polynomials which interests us, then what we know is that $X$ is an ideal and $X$ contains $(H)$. But $X=(H)$ is not obvious to me.

Comment: If $P\in X$, so is $\gcd(P,H)$, but $H$ is irreducible: has no nontrivial divisor.

Comment: @Berci That sounds like an answer to me, if you can expand on the reasoning.